# How to blacklist porn?

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome, traffic-filtering

Is there a way to blacklist sites containing specific keywords? like for example "porn, xxx.. sex". My cheap router can only block 5 specific domains but not sites containing some keywords.

Do you know a software (windows) which runs in the background and does not show any "SITE BLOCKED!" errors in the browser? It should not load the site at all or at least show only blank page.

It can also be a plugin for chrome. (I tried some already)

Comment: which plugins u tried for chrome?

Comment: Is DNS filtering acceptable for application? http://www.opendns.com/ as an example

Comment: Use a DNS service like OpenDNS that allows for a certain level of filtering capability. This is best handled by better hardware.  Your cheap router does not have this capability.

Comment: DNS might be ok but I guess open DNS will show a message in the browser "this site was blocked" or something...

Comment: There are plenty of firewalls that allow to filter out websites. Just use Google and you should be set up in no time.

Comment: just tried opendns and yes, as I said if a site is blocked it shows up in browser "Sorry, but superuser.com is blocked on this network. powered by opendns.com"  - will try some firewall.

Comment: Re simple blocking on words: Blocking based on words triggers many false positives.  (Just ask the people living in Essex (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block based on words , you need "stateful packet inspection", which requires a router/firewall with lots of power and memory.

There are network services like OpenDNS, that allow you to re-configure your home network to use those DNS services. Those can block many sites for you, based on things like porn or adult content.

You may also try some AV's like Kaspersky Internet Security which contain Parental Control features that monitors user access to the Internet. Its main objective is to restrict access, first and foremost, to the following resources: 
   Websites for an adult audience or whose contents deal with pornography, weapons, illicit drugs, violence, etc.User's network access can be controlled by creating a profile in the AV depending upon which content has to be blocked.But it may only come with a paid version.